# Acces element of QVector pointer containing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, qvector

I have the following QVector pointer:

```
QVector<someStruct*>* qvp;
```

How can I acces `someStruct` members? Let's assume that `qvp` has some elements to access allocated eralier. I am trying to do:
`qvp[index]->someStructObject->member` but compiler doesn't allow that.

However, I can do: `qvp->last()->someStructObject->member` as well as `qvp->at(index)->someStructObject->member`, why?

This would work if `qvp` was:

```
QVector<someStruct*>& qvp;
```

Comment: Get the value from pointer ```(*qvp)``` and you can call overloaded [] as you mentioned: ```(*qvp)[index]->someStructObject->member```

Comment: Or you can access it as ```qvp->at(index)->someStructObject->member``` by using ```QVector::at``` method

Comment: I know that `at` works. I just wonder why cant I acces through pointer index.

Comment: In case this is a data structure you have the ability to modify, it's generally not a good idea to have a vector of pointers. It hurts performance because it breaks the locality assumption.

Comment: You probably don't need a pointer to `QVector` either. Anyway, this has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: you can't access through pointer index, because such method is not defined. When you use it by value the overloaded operator [] method is called http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d

Comment: I am not asking either this has anything to do with qt, nor is it a good practice... I just wanted to know why cant I do it, c++ wise. @MaxGo thank you.

Comment: Your question is tagged Qt, talks about QVector, but all of that is unnecessary.